# How do I backup my Minecraft Bedrock world on Xbox One to a flash drive without realms?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I backup my *Minecraft Bedrock* world from my Xbox One to a flash drive? I don’t have realms and don’t want to get realms to backup my world. I want to keep it on a drive separate from the Xbox itself, just in case the Xbox breaks and I can’t recover anything. Also, the cloud backup hasn’t worked. I have multiple Xboxes in my house, and the cloud save doesn’t work. I can’t use my world on a different Xbox without the different Xbox being an old version of the world. In other words, the world doesn’t sync. I’m on an original Xbox One. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an inexpensive way of backing up your Minecraft world.  For this method you will need:

- My Files Explorer installed on your Xbox (available in a 24 hour trial or for >$3),
- An external storage device,
- The account of which created/owns the world

## The Steps

- Connect your external storage device, and wait until it is ready,
- Sign into the account of which created/owns the world you are trying to backup,
- Open up My Files Explorer with the above account,

**If you can't see the filenames, press the button that shows 3 dots, press `Settings`, then choose the bottom left choice for themes or any others that show filenames.**

- Go to Isolated Storage
- Press the `Local` button at the top center of your screen,
- Open `Packages`/`Microsoft.MinecraftUWP...`/`LocalState`/`games`/`com.mojang`/`minecraftWorlds`
- Now find the world folder that you want to backup

**The world names are going to look like gibberish**, you can each folder until you find the one that has the name of your world in `levelname.txt` and/or the `world_icon.jpeg` picture is the right picture.

- Then press the pause button(the button that has 3 lines on it) and select `Copy Folder`
- On the right of your screen should be a menu that has a button called `This Device` press it.
- Go into `Removable Devices`/`(your external storage device)` and press the pause button then hit `Paste`

Once it is done pasting, you can then close the app, shutdown, and take out your drive.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy, but you will need a USB or any hard drive, but if your gonna use only a
single gaming box, Minecraft has an autosave feature, and backup your world.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. This answer could use some more detail; is there anything else you can add, such as steps that the person could take to force a backup manually?

Comment: How would I backup the world though.  Could I have steps?